# React Native get rid of doubble border without using loops

Tags: reactjs, react-native, css-selectors

Is there a way to remove double borders from overlapping border styles without using map or any other loop? Using loops i could specify index and than style based on that index, but how can i do it without looping?

[image: borders image]

```
export function List() {
    return (
    <ListItem>
    <ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      );
    }

export function ListItem() {
    return (
        <Pressable style={styles.container}></Pressable>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "black",
        padding: 20,
    },
});
```

**EDITED**
Right now i am missing the first ListItems top border.

```
 export function ListItem() {
        return (
            <Pressable style={styles.container, ListItem.length === 0
                ? styles.bothBorders
                : ListItem.length === 0
                ? styles.onlyTopBorder
                : styles.onlyBottomBorder,}></Pressable>
        );
    }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: "pink",
            borderColor: "black",
            padding: 20,
        },
 bothBorders: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderTopWidth: 1,
    },
    onlyTopBorder: {
        borderTopWidth: 1,
    },
    onlyBottomBorder: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
    },
    });
```

Comment: Without loops also you need to pass index to that comp, does that work?

Comment: tried to do it but my last ListItem now doesnt have bottom border. You can see my Edited code in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can achieve it by something like this ,

Please check this out and lemme know if it works

Chck this expo snack https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/blessed-salsa

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,Pressable } from 'react-native';




 const ListItem = (props) => {
   const {index} = props || {}
   let newStyles  = {...styles.container};

  if(index === 0 ){
    newStyles.borderTopWidth = 1
  }

  //here its 2 , ideally should be the array.length -1
   if(index === 2 ){
    newStyles.borderBottomWidth = 1
  }

    return (
      <>
        <Pressable style={[newStyles,{

        }]}></Pressable>
        </>
    )
}

const List = ()  => {
    return (
      <>
    <ListItem index={0} / >
    <ListItem index={1}  />
    <ListItem index={2}  />
    </>
      )
}




export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
  <List/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        borderTopWidth: 0.5,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: "black",
        padding: 20,
    },
 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make style that will go to every item besides the first, and give it bottom border. And to first, create separate style and give it only top border. That is the easiest aproach.

Comment: but if i do this and if i have situation where i would have only one ListItem, it would show up without the bottom border?

Comment: @Codeanorr You can do this with condition style: style={items.length===0 ? style.bothBorders : index===0 ? style.onlyTopBorder : style.onlyBottomBorder}.  This is if your items are array of data, and you are creating component for that data. This is common situation.

Comment: i edited my code, could you please take a look at it? Maybe you can spot why i dont have top border on the first element?

Comment: I have created you a snack, this is how you display it in react native. You will always have some kind of data, and you map through it. Here is full working snack https://snack.expo.dev/YGlzr4OhW .On this way you just add data in you array and you display how many you want. If this is you answer please accept it, and if you want upvote it. Big thanks.